# How can I setup a Right Click context menu in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-2.0

I want to create a right click context menu for my textboxes to provide the typical copy/paste functionality. Any ideas on how to go about this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like this is a [way to do this here](http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/sporter/archive/2007/12/09/right-click-event-in-silverlight-1-1-2-0.aspx), [another example here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/justinangel/archive/2007/10/22/question-from-silverlight-forums-custom-context-menu-and-mouse-right-click-event.aspx), and the [most recent one here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/alex_golesh/archive/2008/02/07/how-to-handle-rightclick-mouse-event-in-silverlight.aspx). Using these methods you should be able to show your own context menu. Once you have that you'll need access to the clipboard and there is an [example of this here](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2008/05/21/clipboard-access/).

Good luck!

Answer (score 17):

Right-click context menu is now part of the [Silverlight Control Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/).

What it can and can't do: http://blogs.msdn.com/delay/archive/2010/04/15/alive-and-kickin-new-silverlight-4-toolkit-released-with-today-s-silverlight-4-rtw.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Just for completeness. The above links are for version 1.1 (before beta of 2). The latest version for silverlight 2 is at http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/alex_golesh/archive/2008/05/28/how-to-handle-rightclick-mouse-event-in-silverlight-take-2.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The demo in this open source project does just that while supporting nested menus:

http://sl4popupmenu.codeplex.com/