# ApplicationCommands implementation in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I want to implement `ApplicationCommands` (i.e., Copy & Paste & Help ...) in Silverlight. I show that Silverlight dosen't support this class. Please give me your ideas how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Implement your own Context Menu for your requirement.

Inside the ContextMenu you can call Clipboard.GetText() or Clipboard.SetText()

if you need examples on how to create context menu, please visit this thread.

[Context menu silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304017/how-can-i-setup-a-right-click-context-menu-in-silverlight)